# In Rails 5, how to drop the default value of primary key i.e. 'id' column and make it auto_increment again?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1

In my rails application, there is a table with 'id' column default value set to 0. I want to drop this default value and make this column auto-increment again.
I have tried

> change_column_default(:table_name, :id, nil)

but it doesn't seem to work on primary key such as 'id'

Comment: You just want to reset it to `0` after deleting all the table's records ?

Comment: No, I don't want to remove any records from the table. I just want to drop the `default` i.e. 0 and want to make it again auto-incrementing

Comment: and what will happen with the existing records ?

Comment: they already have ids assigned to them so new records should automatically get incremental ids assigned to them.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
change_column :tabel_name, :column_name, :string, :default => nil
```

Comment: Same result as of `change_column_default`

Comment: can you share you schema.rb or structure.sql
Is the default set there?

Comment: this is the line in `schema.rb` that is setting the `default value` 

```create_table "table_name", id: :integer, default: 0, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1" do |t|```

Answer (score 0):

That's work for me:

```
class MigrationName < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def up
    max_id = TableName.maximum(:id) || 0
    execute "CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS \"table_name_id_seq\" START #{max_id + 1}"
    change_column_default :table_name, :id, -> { "nextval('table_name_id_seq'::regclass)" }
  end

  def down
    change_column_default :table_name, :id, nil
    execute 'DROP SEQUENCE "table_name_id_seq"'
  end
end
```